# Preorder on Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Given a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, define $\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}} = \{(a,b) \in X^2 : a \in \overline{\{b\}}\}$.

Prove that $\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}}$ is a *preorder*, that is, transitive and reflexive.

---

Here is my understanding of the problem:

We need to show that it is both reflexive and transitive.

- $a \trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}} a$ for all $a$ since $(a,a) \in X^2$
- $a \trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}} b$ and $b\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}} c$ implies that $a \trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}} c$.

I am unsure about this one, but here is what I've got:

if $a \trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}} b$, then we have that $(a,b) \in X^2$ and if we are also given that $b \trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}} c$, then $(b,c) \in X^2$. However, we are told that $a \in \overline{\{b\}}$, and by the second relation between $b$ and $c$, we would have $b \in \overline{\{c\}}$.

At this point, I want to say that $b = \overline{\{b\}}$ and use that to associate $a$ and $c$; however, may we assume that $b = \overline{\{b\}}$, or would we need a new direction to proceed in this manner?

Much thanks in advance for your attention to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $a\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}}a$, it’s not enough to say that $\langle a,a\rangle\in X^2$: you must also point out that $a\in\operatorname{cl}\{a\}$.

You certainly can’t say that $b=\operatorname{cl}\{b\}$, for two reasons. First, $b$ is a point of $X$ and $\operatorname{cl}\{b\}$ is a subset of $X$, so they aren’t even the same kind of object: at best you could have $\{b\}=\operatorname{cl}\{b\}$. However, there is no reason to suppose that this is actually the case. It’s entirely possible, for instance, that $\operatorname{cl}\{b\}=X$.

For transitivity you’re assuming that $a\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}}b$ and $b\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}}c$, so by definition you know that $a\in\operatorname{cl}\{b\}$ and $b\in\operatorname{cl}\{c\}$. You want to show that $a\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{T}}c$, i.e., that $a\in\operatorname{cl}\{c\}$. It suffices to show that $\operatorname{cl}\{b\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\{c\}$; can you see why this is true?

Comment: My book uses definition for closure of a set as $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$ which translates into saying that a point $x$ is either in $A$ or every open set containing $x$ contains a point distinct from $x$. Using this, then if $a \in \overline{b}$, then $a \in b \cup a \in \overline{b}$. But $b \in c \cup \overline{c}$, thus $\overline{b} \subseteq \overline{c}$. Is this why that statement is true?

Comment: @Jamil: You’re still confusing points with sets when you write $a\in b\cup a\in\overline{b}$. Correction: $a\in\{b\}\cup\operatorname{cl}\{b\}$, so $a\in\{b\}$ or $a\in\operatorname{cl}\{b\}$. I think, however, that you actually meant that $a\in\{b\}\cup\{b\}'$, so that $a\in\{b\}$ or $a\in\{b\}'$. You have similar notational errors throughout the comment. \\ You’re approaching the reason, but you’re not really there, and you’re making it harder than necessary. You know that $b\in\operatorname{cl}\{c\}$; this means that $\{b\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\{c\}$. You should know that if ...

Comment: ... $A\subseteq B$, then $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B$, so you can conclude that $\operatorname{cl}\{b\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\{c\}$, and at that point you’re almost done.

Comment: thank you very much for this. I have shown that if $A \subseteq B$, then cl $A \subseteq$ cl$B$ on a previous occasion. Your assistance is always instructive and much appreciated.

Comment: @Jamil: You’re very welcome; glad to help!